# How to use AnimatedStateListDrawable inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-selector

I am trying to make a `RecyclerView` of a list of Tasks with *done* and *undone* states and I want to create a beautiful transition between those states.

So I created an `animated-selector` to make the transition between the states, but the transitions is not working when I use it inside the `RecyclerView`, when I test it on a Button/ImageView outside the `RecyclerView` it works as it should.

[Screen with the RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQPg2.png)

#### aslv_status.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_done"
        android:state_selected="true" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/undone"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_undone" />
    <transition
        android:drawable="@drawable/avd_done_to_undone"
        android:fromId="@id/done"
        android:toId="@id/undone" />
    <transition
        android:drawable="@drawable/avd_undone_to_undone"
        android:fromId="@id/undone"
        android:toId="@id/done" />
</animated-selector>
```

I toggle the attribute `isDone` of the `Task` in the adapter item `onClickListener` and seted the `animated-selector` as the `android:src` of the `AppCompatImageView` of my recyclerView adapter item:

#### item_task.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.toggleTaskState(task)}" >
    ...
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_status_image"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/aslv_status"
        .../>
    ...
```

#### TaskViewModel.kt

```
fun toggleTaskState(task: Task) = viewModelScope.launch {
    task.isDone = !task.isDone
    taskRepository.updateTask(task)
}
```

On `TaskAdapter` on `init` I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when the liveData *allTasks* change, and on `TaskViewHolder` binding I updated the `AppCompatImageView` selected state.

#### TaskAdapter.kt

```
private var allTasks = viewModel.allTasks

init {
    viewModel.allTasks.observe(lifecycle, {
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
}
...
class TaskViewHolder(private var binding: ItemTaskBinding, private val viewModel: TaskViewModel)
    : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(task: Task) {
        binding.task = task
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.imageviewStatusImage.isSelected = task.isDone
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

I think the problem is the `notifyDataSetChanged()` called when I change the state of the Task object, because I imagine the `RecyclerView` updates the layout abruptly and doesn't show the transition state animation, but if I don't call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` the `RecyclerView` won't change the list items state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding in case someone goes through the same situation as me.

In the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method documentation:

> RecyclerView will attempt to synthesize visible structural change
> events for adapters that report that they have {@link #hasStableIds()
> stable IDs} when this method is used. This can help for the purposes
> of animation and visual object persistence but individual item views
> will still need to be rebound and relaid out.

So I setted `hasStableIds()` to my `Adapter` and it worked!

```
val taskAdapter = TaskAdapter(this, taskViewModel)
taskAdapter.setHasStableIds(true)
```